# Automorphisms and even permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

One question, two parts...

(a) Consider the group $(Z_n, + \mod{n})$. If $n$ is an odd prime number, determine (with proofs) if all automorphisms of $(Z_n, + \mod{n})$ are even permutations of $Z_n$.

(b) Determine the automorphism group of the group $S_3$ (under functional composition).

Strategy?

Comment: A strategy to (b) can be found in the answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124149/what-is-the-number-of-automorphisms-including-identity-for-permutation-group?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

(a) Consider $f\colon Z_n\to Z_n$, $k\mapsto -k\pmod n$. As a permutation, $f$ consists of $\frac{n-1}2$ two-cycles. If $n\equiv 3\pmod 4$, thsi is an odd permutation.

(b) $S_3$ is generated by $\alpha=(1\,2)$ and $\beta=(1\,3)$. For an automorphism $f$, these must map to different elements of order two, hence elements of the form $f(\alpha)=(a\,b)$ and $f(\beta)=(c\,d)$. Since $S_3$ acts only onf $\{1,2,3\}$, two of the numbers must coincide, wlog. $a=c$. Then $f$ is just conjugation with $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\a&b&c\end{pmatrix}$. We conclude that $\operatorname{Aut}(S_3)=\operatorname{Inn}(S_3)\cong S_3$.

Comment: So, in (a) we can show that not all automorphisms of $(Z_n, + \mod{n})$ are even permutations of $Z_n$. Regarding (b), our class has not yet learned anything about inner automorphisms. How can I show that $Aut(S_3) \cong S_3$ without referencing inner automorphisms?